# Knowledge article reporting "Number of results" issue

Tags: reporting, knowledge, articles

**Iam currently having some truble** :(
We want to report keywords which were used in the article search.
But when we look at the report and the field: "Number of results"
We only see odd numbers like for  keyword "contract" its shows smth. like 0.50 or another key word shows the numer 2.3750

So our question is how can it be that a keyword result is uneven like 2.3750 ? How can a keyword displayed 2.3750 times?

Example in Screenshot:
[image]

Please see here copied part from Konwledge help article:

Number of Results  =  The number of search results that were returned for the search term. If Duration is also included, this value is aggregated based on the time period specified.

Does anbody has a hint on that?

Answer (score 0):

It's an average over the duration you specify, it won't always be an integer value. For example if you run two searches and one has 5 results and one has 6 results, your Number of Results will be 5.5.

Thanks,
Badan